# Twitter Bootstrap: Changing div order in mobile device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My code given bellow

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2">
                @Html.Partial("LeftNavBar")
            </div>

            <div class="span8">
                    @RenderBody()
            </div>

            <div class="span2">
                @Html.Partial("RightNavBar")
            </div>
   </div>
```

Now in the mobile browser

[image]

If I want following ordering in mobile browser, then what I have to do?

1. @RenderBody()(LogOn Form)
2. LeftNavBar
3. RightNavBar

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this easily with floats if the body were first in the source order, above the left and right menus. Then all you would need to do is float the left nav left and the right nav right; and on smaller devices simply stack the body and navs.

Comment: It was pretty clear: you need to move the body above the left nav bar. Then you can float the menus left and right on larger screens, or just stack the content on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

Try with box-ordinal-group CSS 3 property.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-ordinal-group.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_box-ordinal-group